# Dictionary style replacement for columns in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

I am looking for an efficient way to replace different columns NA's with different values depending on the column. Let's say I have a dataframe that looks as such:

```
miles_ran    miles_cycled
3            9
4            NA
NA           NA
9            2
NA           12
```

I would like a dictionary style replacement whereby I can specify the column name and the value to replace with as such:

```
dict(miles_ran = 0, miles_cycled = 10)
```

and my replaced dataframe values look as such:

```
miles_ran    miles_cycled
3            9
4            10
0            10
9            2
0            12
```

Is there a way to do this instead of using a line of code to replace NA's for each column?

Thanks

Comment: DId you get the result you hoped for?

Comment: I used version without tibble and used that but I'm sure the results will be the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  miles_ran = c(3,4,NA,9,NA),
  miles_cycled = c(9,NA,NA,2,12)
)


df %>%
  replace_na(df, list(miles_ran = 0, miles_cycled = 10))
```